# Upgrade to Joomla 3 not available

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-2.5, upgrade

I've got a Joomla 2.5.28 site that I want to upgrade to Joomla 3.3.x.

All available docs say all I need to do is set my update server to short term, and the 3.x series upgrade option will appear. Well, it doesn't! I've cleared my caches, logged out and back in, etc. and the control panel shows the nag that Joomla 2.5 will be desupported soon-- but the Joomla Update view just says

> You already have the latest Joomla! version, 2.5.28.

I don't see any option to begin the migration.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had this issue a long time ago too. I cleared and purged all available caches, tried again and it worked. You do have an alternative which is download the update package:

[Joomla_3.3.6-Stable-Update_Package.zip](http://joomlacode.org/gf/download/frsrelease/19823/161247/%4a%6f%6f%6d%6c%61%5f%33%2e%33%2e%36%2d%53%74%61%62%6c%65%2d%55%70%64%61%74%65%5f%50%61%63%6b%61%67%65%2e%7a%69%70)

Once done, install it as you would any other extension via the Extension Manager in the Joomla backend. Please remember to take a backup of your 2.5 site (including the database) before you do anything.

Hope this helps

Comment: @Lodder-- thanks, didn't realize I could just upload the update package. That ended up working, though I never did get the updater to give the option to go from 2.5.28 -> 3.x, despite clearing caches and setting to short term support.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

1. Go to Components>Joomla! Update
2. Click the Options icon in the upper right corner
3. If it's on Long Term Support, switch it to Short Term Support and save

See if that makes the 3.3.X update show up.

I believe it's a safe guard so you don't accidentally bump a site to 3.x without thinking about it first.

Comment: Thanks but see above- it's already on short term.

Comment: Sheesh I read that twice and STILL missed it. Well, I'll leave this anyway in case someone is just looking for a possible answer as to why it's not showing up. It IS odd though. I just did this on a 2.5 site and it flipped to offer me 3.3.6 as soon as I saved, so something's definitely off on your site. Try the updater link in Lodder's answer.

Answer (score 2):

The steps described by Brian Peat should work. Although I had the same problem that the site kept saying that it already was at the highest version 2.5.x.
I ran into this problem on a copy of the site, for upgrade testing. The copy site allowed me to update to the latest version of 2.5. After the update I switched to Short Term Support and the site kept saying it was at the highest level.
Checking back on the original site, that still allowed me to update to the latest version of 2.5. However, after checking for updates again (simply clicking the Find Updates button again), the site said it was at the highest level. Swithing between Long Term and Short Term made no difference.
So, there must be an issue somewhere. I found that for some reason an entry for the Joomla Core update vanishes from the #__updates table. To fix this do this:

1. Go to Extensions > Extension Manager
2. Select Database
3. Click the Fix button
4. Return to Components > Joomla! Update
5. Make sure you select Short Term Support.

The update to 3.x should be present.

Answer (score 0):

Purging the Joomla cache always seemed to fix this problem for me until today when I also had to purge the cache at Extensions -> Extension Manager -> Update.

Once the update cache was cleared, the Joomla update from 2.5.28 to 3.5.1 was then offered.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your PHP to a minimum of 5.6

Worked for me.

Update didn't show with php5.4  but as soon as I changed it, it appeared.

Comment: Thanks for sharing and welcome to JSE, Damian.  Please take a moment to register your account, add some details to your profile, and take the Tour to earn your first badge.  I hope you continue to chime in when you can.